# LINQ Check for Nulls with OR

Tags: performance, linq, logic

I have 2 values in table User: Address1, Address2. Both could be null. As part of a filter method, I am attempting something like the below:

```
var tempUsers = users.Where(q => q.Address1.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower()) || q.Address2.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower()));
```

This is returning a Null Reference Exception, and rightly so.

1. Linq queries need to be handled against null values
2. I would be attempting
   null.ToLower() and null.Contains() within the query

What is the best way to go around it? If it was a simple 1 field Query, for e.g. just Address1, I would have simply filtered out all items with empty Address1, and continued normally in the second query. In this case, both fields are important to the filtering, as in, the input: address could be either in Address1 **or** Address2 of the User table.

I know this might not be possible in a 1 liner, but what is the best approach to take in terms of time and performance?

Comment: try this : var tempUsers = users.Where(q => ( q.Address1 != null && q.Address1.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower()) )|| (q.Address2 != null && q.Address2.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower()) ) );

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var address = (GetAddressFromOuterWorld() ?? String.Empty).ToLower();
var tempUsers = users.Where(user => (user.Address1 ?? String.Empty).ToLower().Contains(address) 
                                 || (user.Address2 ?? String.Empty).ToLower().Contains(address));
```

This definitely works with LINQ to Object, but probably fails with LINQ to SQL, but in that case you normally write `user.Address1 == address || user.Addrss2 == address` and your database uses a [case-insensitive collate setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add null checks like this.

```
var tempUsers = users.Where(q =>
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Address1) && q.Address1.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower())) ||
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Address2) && q.Address2.ToLower().Contains(address.ToLower())));
```